# Is it possible to dynamically assign styleid to all elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css, struts-1

I'm working on a school project which makes use of struts1.

However I have found out, there are many elements that don't have a "styleid" assigned to it yet.
Is there a way to dynamically assign elements with "styleid" using javascript?

In the existing code, there are elements accessed by getElementById() method but with no "styleid" yet. Have tried manually assigning each by placing "styleid" to every element.

```
<html:select property="classno" styleId="category"/>


<html:select property="classname" />
<html:select property="studentname" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its possible via Jquery.

All you need to do is import Jquery (a Javascript Library) and use "attr" method:

```
 $("yourElement").attr("styleId","category");
```